# A high quality question as a low quality answer

Tags: discussion, review-queues, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

So I've tried my hardest to narrow flags down and sometimes it's splitting hairs. But this one really seems to be tricky. It showed up in the Late Answers queue and it took me a few minutes of reading it before flagging it not an answer

[Access to current_user from within a model in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568218/access-to-current-user-from-within-a-model-in-ruby-on-rails/28136937#28136937)

The reasoning is simple

- It ends with a question
- It doesn't seem to answer anything the OP posited (it references the same function)

Ironically I think it would make a really good related **question**. For that reason, I think the reviewers got it wrong. Am I wrong?

Comment: Link to the review?

Comment: @AstroCB http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6843014 (Also went through late and first answer reviews)

Comment: What a peculiar case. I've left a comment on the answer in hopes that the (unregistered) user will notice and follow up.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like either an answer *or* a "high quality" question. It looks more like one person's story of accessing the current user, with a bit of mild ranting thrown in for flavor.

From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> **Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague**

This is nowhere near that, and the only question the wall of text ever reaches is the vague:

> What have I missed